# How to solve this error? I have tried all the solutions but none of them work

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, dynamic, syntax-error

```sql
    SELECT *

from sys.databases

where name = 'quizapplication'
GO

SELECT submittedanswer.sa, answer.ans;
FROM answer
INNER JOIN ( SELECT TOP 1 sa FROM submittedanswer order by ID DESC) AS submitted
ON submittedanswer.sa=answer.ans

GO
```

and this error keeps popping up

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 9
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'.
> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 10
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'order'.

---

Edit, per suggestion of an answer, I have tried removing the `;`, it did not help:

```sql
USE [C:\USERS\SYEDH\ONEDRIVE\DESKTOP\QUIZAPPS\QUIZAPPS\APP_DATA\QUIZAPPLICATION.MDF]
GO
SELECT  submittedanswer.sa, answer.ans
from answer
INNER JOIN( SELECT TOP 1 sa FROM submittedanswer order by ID DESC) AS submitted 
ON submittedanswer.sa=answer.ans
GO
```

While This Gives Me This Error I Have Removed The ";" Still It Doesn`t Help

> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
> The multi-part identifier "submittedanswer.sa" could not be bound.
> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
> The multi-part identifier "submittedanswer.sa" could not be bound.

Comment: Please don't SHOUT AT US; we can hear (read) your inside voice just fine. Thanks. Also, if you had *really* tried everything, you would have fixed the problem...

Comment: `submittedanswer.sa` should be `submitted.sa` in both the `SELECT` and `ON` (those are on lines 3 and 5, as the errors tell you). This is just a typographical error.

Comment: Also do you ***really*** have a database called `C:\USERS\SYEDH\ONEDRIVE\DESKTOP\QUIZAPPS\QUIZAPPS\APP_DATA\QUIZAPPLICATION.MDF`??? You *need* to fix that database name if so.

Comment: I must admit, however, I'm not sure this is going to do what you want afterwards; as the subquery will only return 1 row, not 1 row each each answer (which I suspect is what you are *really* after.

Comment: @Larnu Yes and that too the code however works and yes i have that database i am still new to this that`s why it`s like that anyways how can i make a multiple question based quiz can you help me out please?

Comment: *"how can i make a multiple question based quiz"* that is far too broad a question for [so] and "help me" isn't an answerable question.

Comment: @Larnu so what`s the query for checking answers of two or more questions at once and i am new to sql and aspnet and it`s for a project with end date of 9/12 i will appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

You have aliased `( SELECT TOP 1 sa FROM submittedanswer order by ID DESC)` as `submitted`.

Try referencing `submittedanswer.sa` as `submitted.sa` instead.

Comment: I suspect you didn't apply the change in both places.